# SELECT query in cassandra

Tags: sql, select, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql

I'm getting error "line 2:28 no viable alternative at input 'api_version As ApiVersion" In cassandra. I'm new to cassandra.
My query is.

```
    "SELECT 'api_version As ApiVersion',
            'sid As CarrierSid',
            'phone_number As PhoneNumber',
            'network As Network',
            'wireless As Wireless',
            'zipCode As ZipCode',
            'city As City',
            'price As Price',
            'date_time As CreatedDate', 
            FROM carrier";
```

Comment: I suspect we may need more code than this to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for ur response..how can I use aliases for column name in cassendra ? Is that the correct way that I mentioned in the query?

Comment: Cassandra 2.0 [appears to support](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0) aliases, so I don't know why your query fails.  Can you remove the aliases and try running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "SELECT api_version As ApiVersion,
            sid As CarrierSid,
            phone_number As PhoneNumber,
            network As Network,
            wireless As Wireless,
            zipCode As ZipCode,
            city As City,
            price As Price,
            date_time As CreatedDate, 
            FROM carrier";
```

You have single quotes (') which is making query to fail. Try without it.

Comment: Yeah Thanks...I already changed my query like this,
'SELECT api_version As ApiVersion,
sid As CarrierSid,
phone_number As PhoneNumber,network As Network,wireless As Wireless,zipCode As ZipCode,city As City,price As Price,date_time As CreatedDate FROM carrier;';